# How can I check if email and password exists for same student?[Spring Boot API]

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, rest

I have database table called student, contains fname, lname, city, email & password. I want to create an Spring boot API, which will check email & password for login purpose. I have tried something but this is checking email in total student table and password in total student table.

**I want to find email first then check if given password exists for same email.**

Please help me over here.
My code in controller:-

```
@GetMapping("login/{email}/{pass}")
public String login(@PathVariable("email") String email, @PathVariable("pass") String pass) {
        
        Boolean isEmail = studentService.existsByEmail(student.getEmail());
        Boolean isPassword = studentService.existsByPassword(student.getPassword());
        if(isEmail) {
            if(isPassword) {
                return "student exists";
            }
            return "Not found";
        }
        return "Did Not found";
    }
```

Final Solution:- (Special thanks to all.)

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestBody Student student) {
        if(studentService.existsByEmailAndPassword(student.getEmail(), student.getPassword())) {
            String resultString = "Logged in Successfully";
            return resultString;
        }
        return "Student doesn't exist with the given email id:- " + student.getEmail();
    }
```

Comment: I did it my own.

Comment: If you figured out a solution, it's best to post it as an answer and accept, so people will be aware that it's answered.

Comment: Tbh, your solution looks wrong for login check -  you will login student `A`, even if input password is wrong, but there exist student `B` with inputted password.

Comment: Correct, It is logging in with A's email and B's Password. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution seems wrong since it could return false positives.

Your solution:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public String login(@RequestBody Student student) {
    if(studentService.existsByEmail(student.getEmail())) {
        if(studentService.existsByPassword(student.getPassword())) {
            return "student Exists";
        }
        return "Incorrect Password";
    }
    return "Student doesn't exist with this email id:- " + student.getEmail() ;
}
```

Let's say there are 2 students, Mark with email address "mark@student.com" and password "markymark", and Kim with email address "kim@student.com" and password "kimmykimkim".

If your request specifies email "mark@student.com" and password "kimmykimkim" then the code in your solution would return "student Exists". mark@student.com does indeed exist, however, their password is not "kimmykimkim".

You could fix it by adding and using the following repository method:

```
existsByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
```

Is this for a school assignment? If not you should consider storing your passwords encrypted. You'd then first need to retrieve the password of a student, given their email address. Then you need to compare the plaintext password to the encrypted password using a password encoder. [This](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/authentication/password-storage.html) spring security reference can be useful.

Comment: Yes, You are correct. I am getting results as you said. I had also tried before with your repository method, but did not find way to check if they are existing or not in controller. Could you please put some more idea on it?

Comment: Yahoooo... your solution worked for me....And Logged in successfully.

Answer (score 1):

In your @Repository you need a `findByEmail` method, either with @Query annotation and your implementation or shipped with spring naming conventions(in that case read about Spring JpaRepository).
This method should return whole Student object and you can check its password.

Comment: I have setup everything you said, but I want to check of email and password for one student. Like we do login check. Check the question I have updated with my code in controller.

Comment: Your approach is wrong.
1. There might be different students - one with wanted email and other one with wanted password.

I assume what you want to do is:
- if non-existent email return information that there is no such email
- if existent email return information about bad password for this email
- if password fitting email, return success.

2. You are making 2 queries which are not needed, and it decreases application performance.

Rather then checking for existence via `exists` methods, retrieve Student from table by `findByEmail` and check if his password matches desired one.